# call a payable function from front end app!

Tags: solidity, web3js

solidity code:

```
function fundIt() public payable returns (bool) {
            require(msg.value > .01 ether);
            address addr = this;
            donors.push(msg.sender);
            amount = addr.balance;

        }
```

and here is how I am calling it:

```
const $fundIt = async () =>{

       const fundit = await  mycontract.methods.fundIt({
                                                        from: '0xbf443ed3b73159d5bf427568359c7de4103413c3', 
                                                        value: 3 
                                                       })
                                                .then(res => 
                                                      console.log('Success', res))
                                                .catch(err => console.log(err))                                                             

     }
```

it is not working!! all I got was:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of parameters for "fundIt". Got 1 expected 0!

Does anyone know why this is happening? 
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `send()` after calling `fundIt()`.
You need to specify `from` and `value` in `send()`

```
       const fundit = await  mycontract.methods.fundIt().send({
                                                    from: '0xbf443ed3b73159d5bf427568359c7de4103413c3', 
                                                    value: 3 
                                                   })
                                            .then(res => 
                                                  console.log('Success', res))
                                            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: thx! now I have this err popping up: 
```
 Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

Comment: The amount you enter for `value` is in `wei`.  If you wish to send `3 ether`, try setting `value: 3*10**18`